# How do I fix RuntimeError: An attempt has been made to start a new process before the current process has finished its bootstrapping phase?

Tags: python, pytorch, fast-ai

I'm in the midst of learning fastai and I'm constantly running into the '[Errno 32] Broken pipe' error, I have the necessary packages in pip and conda,
and also running an Intel i5-2520M 2.5GHz, Windows 10 64-bit, 
Python

```
3.7.4
```

, and the CPU version of Pytorch since I don't have a dedicated GPU, and the latest Pytorch

```
torch           1.3.0+cpu
torchvision     0.4.1+cpu
```

And fastai

```
fastai          1.0.58
```

After launching the script in conda in my environment I get the following in my terminal

```
------->> biwi_head_pose\09\frame_00667_rgb.jpg
---- Done Gathering Data
epoch     train_loss  valid_loss  time
------->> biwi_head_pose\09\frame_00667_rgb.jpg--------------------------| 0.00% [0/237 00:00<00:00]
---- Done Gathering Data
epoch     train_loss  valid_loss  time
LR Finder is complete, type {learner_name}.recorder.plot() to see the graph.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Eric\Anaconda3\envs\fastai\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 105, in spawn_main
    exitcode = _main(fd)
  File "C:\Users\Eric\Anaconda3\envs\fastai\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 114, in _main
    prepare(preparation_data)
  File "C:\Users\Eric\Anaconda3\envs\fastai\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 225, in prepare
    _fixup_main_from_path(data['init_main_from_path'])
  File "C:\Users\Eric\Anaconda3\envs\fastai\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 277, in _fixup_main_from_path
    run_name="__mp_main__")
  File "C:\Users\Eric\Anaconda3\envs\fastai\lib\runpy.py", line 263, in run_path
    pkg_name=pkg_name, script_name=fname)
  File "C:\Users\Eric\Anaconda3\envs\fastai\lib\runpy.py", line 96, in _run_module_code
    mod_name, mod_spec, pkg_name, script_name)
  File "C:\Users\Eric\Anaconda3\envs\fastai\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\Eric\Desktop\fastai Practice\L3\HeadPose.py", line 39, in <module>
    learn.lr_find()
  File "C:\Users\Eric\Anaconda3\envs\fastai\lib\site-packages\fastai\train.py", line 41, in lr_find
    learn.fit(epochs, start_lr, callbacks=[cb], wd=wd)
  File "C:\Users\Eric\Anaconda3\envs\fastai\lib\site-packages\fastai\basic_train.py", line 200, in fit
    fit(epochs, self, metrics=self.metrics, callbacks=self.callbacks+callbacks)
  File "C:\Users\Eric\Anaconda3\envs\fastai\lib\site-packages\fastai\basic_train.py", line 99, in fit
    for xb,yb in progress_bar(learn.data.train_dl, parent=pbar):
  File "C:\Users\Eric\Anaconda3\envs\fastai\lib\site-packages\fastprogress\fastprogress.py", line 72, in __iter__
    for i,o in enumerate(self._gen):
  File "C:\Users\Eric\Anaconda3\envs\fastai\lib\site-packages\fastai\basic_data.py", line 75, in __iter__
    for b in self.dl: yield self.proc_batch(b)
  File "C:\Users\Eric\Anaconda3\envs\fastai\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\dataloader.py", line 193, in __iter__
    return _DataLoaderIter(self)
  File "C:\Users\Eric\Anaconda3\envs\fastai\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\dataloader.py", line 469, in __init__
    w.start()
  File "C:\Users\Eric\Anaconda3\envs\fastai\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 112, in start
    self._popen = self._Popen(self)
  File "C:\Users\Eric\Anaconda3\envs\fastai\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 223, in _Popen
LR Finder is complete, type {learner_name}.recorder.plot() to see the graph.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "HeadPose.py", line 39, in <module>
    learn.lr_find()
  File "C:\Users\Eric\Anaconda3\envs\fastai\lib\site-packages\fastai\train.py", line 41, in lr_find
    learn.fit(epochs, start_lr, callbacks=[cb], wd=wd)
  File "C:\Users\Eric\Anaconda3\envs\fastai\lib\site-packages\fastai\basic_train.py", line 200, in fit
    fit(epochs, self, metrics=self.metrics, callbacks=self.callbacks+callbacks)
  File "C:\Users\Eric\Anaconda3\envs\fastai\lib\site-packages\fastai\basic_train.py", line 99, in fit
    for xb,yb in progress_bar(learn.data.train_dl, parent=pbar):
  File "C:\Users\Eric\Anaconda3\envs\fastai\lib\site-packages\fastprogress\fastprogress.py", line 72, in __iter__
    for i,o in enumerate(self._gen):
  File "C:\Users\Eric\Anaconda3\envs\fastai\lib\site-packages\fastai\basic_data.py", line 75, in __iter__
return _default_context.get_context().Process._Popen(process_obj)
  File "C:\Users\Eric\Anaconda3\envs\fastai\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 322, in _Popen
    for b in self.dl: yield self.proc_batch(b)
  File "C:\Users\Eric\Anaconda3\envs\fastai\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\dataloader.py", line 193, in __iter__
    return Popen(process_obj)
      File "C:\Users\Eric\Anaconda3\envs\fastai\lib\multiprocessing\popen_spawn_win32.py", line 46, in __init__
return _DataLoaderIter(self)
  File "C:\Users\Eric\Anaconda3\envs\fastai\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\dataloader.py", line 469, in __init__
    w.start()
  File "C:\Users\Eric\Anaconda3\envs\fastai\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 112, in start
    self._popen = self._Popen(self)
  File "C:\Users\Eric\Anaconda3\envs\fastai\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 223, in _Popen
    return _default_context.get_context().Process._Popen(process_obj)
  File "C:\Users\Eric\Anaconda3\envs\fastai\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 322, in _Popen
    return Popen(process_obj)
  File "C:\Users\Eric\Anaconda3\envs\fastai\lib\multiprocessing\popen_spawn_win32.py", line 89, in __init__
        reduction.dump(process_obj, to_child)prep_data = spawn.get_preparation_data(process_obj._name)

  File "C:\Users\Eric\Anaconda3\envs\fastai\lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 60, in dump
  File "C:\Users\Eric\Anaconda3\envs\fastai\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 143, in get_preparation_data
    _check_not_importing_main()
  File "C:\Users\Eric\Anaconda3\envs\fastai\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 136, in _check_not_importing_main
    is not going to be frozen to produce an executable.''')
RuntimeError:
        An attempt has been made to start a new process before the
        current process has finished its bootstrapping phase.

        This probably means that you are not using fork to start your
        child processes and you have forgotten to use the proper idiom
        in the main module:

            if __name__ == '__main__':
                freeze_support()
                ...

        The "freeze_support()" line can be omitted if the program
        is not going to be frozen to produce an executable.
    ForkingPickler(file, protocol).dump(obj)
BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

As you can see Errno 32 opens up, I have looked around and people say put `if __name__ == '__main__':` before the training code, however when I do this the error goes away but it does not train.

So this is what I have done(HeadPose.py), first we get the data from the path and convert the images to coords to train

```
from fastai.vision import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Get Data & Convert to Matrices
path = 'C:\\Users\\Eric\\Desktop\\fastai Practice\\L3\\'
cal = np.genfromtxt(path+'biwi_head_pose\\01\\rgb.cal', skip_footer=6); cal
fname = 'biwi_head_pose\\09\\frame_00667_rgb.jpg'

def img2txt_name(f): return path+f'{str(f)[:-7]}pose.txt'
img=open_image(path+fname)
#img.show()

ctr = np.genfromtxt(img2txt_name(fname), skip_header=3); ctr
def convert_biwi(coords):
    c1 = coords[0] * cal[0][0]/coords[2] + cal[0][2]
    c2 = coords[1] * cal[1][1]/coords[2] + cal[1][2]
    return tensor([c2,c1])

def get_ctr(f):
    ctr = np.genfromtxt(img2txt_name(f), skip_header=3)
    return convert_biwi(ctr)

def get_ip(img,pts): return ImagePoints(FlowField(img.size, pts), scale=True)
get_ctr(fname)
ctr = get_ctr(fname)
#img.show(y=get_ip(img,ctr), figsize=(6,6))
```

then this Code creates a dataset from the files in the `biwi_head_pose` folder

```
# Creating a dataset
data = (PointsItemList.from_folder('biwi_head_pose')
        .split_by_valid_func(lambda o: o.parent.name=='13')
        .label_from_func(get_ctr)
        .transform(get_transforms(), tfm_y=True, size=(120,160))
        .databunch().normalize(imagenet_stats))

data.show_batch(3, figsize=(9,6))
print('---- Done Gathering Data')
```

and this is the code that trains the data with a Convolutional Neural Network.

```
#Train model
learn = cnn_learner(data, models.resnet34)
learn.lr_find()
learn.recorder.plot()
lr = 2e-2
learn.fit_one_cycle(5, slice(lr))
print('---- Saving as 3-stage-1')
learn.save(p+'3-stage-1')
print('---- Saved!')
print('---- Loading 3-stage-1')
learn.load(p+'3-stage-1');
learn.show_results()
print('---- Done!')
plt.show()
```

I'm following the tutorial from this fastai github page:
https://github.com/fastai/course-v3/blob/master/nbs/dl1/lesson3-head-pose.ipynb

Comment: Hi @cck, a good question does not have tags in the title name. Please stop adding them: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130208

Comment: Also `Errno 32 Broken pipe` is not the essence of your problem. This is just an artifact of one of the processes dying and the other one failing to communicate with it over an established pipe. Hence: Broken pipe.